# JS: If 'X' is mentioned anywhere in the LIST. Display

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, caml, query

My list categories:

- Cats
- Dogs
- Cats and Dogs

What i want to achieve:
If 'Cats' is ANYWHERE mentioned in the list field, display data in HTML table. This means category

- Cats
- Cats and Dogs

will appear in the HTML table.

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> get() ;function get() { var method = "GetListItems";                
var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                    
var list = "Animal Zoo";
var value = "Cats";                   
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
var query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>" + value + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>"; 
</OrderBy></Query>";                  

$().SPServices
({ operation: method, async: false, webURL: webURL, listName: list,
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
CAMLQuery: query, completefunc: function (xData, Status)
{ $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
{ var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
var update  =  $(this).attr("ows_Update");
var date  =  $(this).attr("ows_Date");

$("#myDataTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
"<td align='left'>"+date+"</td>" + "<td align='left'>"+update+"</td>" + "</tr>");

}); } }); };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `<Contains>` instead of `<Eq>` in your caml query:

```
var query = "<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Category' /><Value Type='Text'>" + value + "</Value></Contains></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>"; 
</OrderBy></Query>";
```

More on `<Contains>` element can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms196501.aspx).